# UIImageViewを含んだViewにeventを設定したが、UIImageView部分でハンドリングしてくれない

Tags: ios, uiimage

下記のようにViewを作ってeventと関数のひも付けを行ったのですが、UIImageView部分がeventに反応しません。何か追加で設定すべき項目があるのでしょうか

・storyboard上でUILabelとUIImageViewを含んだViewを作り、ClassをUIControlに
・viewController上でTouchDownと関数のひも付け

```
 [_control addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: 削除されてしまったようですが、userInteractionEnabledをyesしていますか？との解答で原因が分かりました。
view側でもUIImgeView側でもuserInteractionEnabledにチェックが入っていましたが、むしろソレが問題でした。view側で一括してeventを拾う場合、内部のUIImgeViewのuserInteractionEnabledはNOに設定する必要があったようです。

Answer (score -1):

UILabelのインスタンスと、UIImageViewのインスタンスのプロパティ「**userInteractionEnabled**」を有効（YES）に変更してください。この操作は、プログラムでも、Storyboardでも行えます。
userInteractionEnabledは、UIViewのプロパティであり、デフォルトはYESです。つまりユーザの操作に反応することがデフォルトになっています。しかし、UILabelとUIImageViewのみ、デフォルトがNOになっています。ユーザの操作に反応してもらいたくない、「ただの」画像やテキストを表示するために、UIImageViewとUILabelを使用するケースが大半を占めるからだと考えられます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

あ、一足遅かったですか……このままでは中途半端なので、質問に対する回答から外れますが、関連するTipsを載せて、ちょっとだけかっこうをつけておこうと思います。

UIControlのサブクラスではない、UILabel、UIImageViewをタップして、アクションメソッドを実行する方法を載せておきます。これを使えば、背後にUIControlのサブクラスを配置する必要がなくなります。

それにはUIGestureRecognizerを使います。今回はそのサブクラスUITapGestureRecognizerで、タップに反応するUIImageViewインスタンスを作ります。

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

// タップに反応するイメージビュー
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // UItapGestureRecognizerインスタンスを作成し、イメージビューに組みこむ。 
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(imageTap:)];
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer: tapGestureRecognizer];
}

// イメージビューをタップしたら呼び出される、アクションメソッド。
- (void)imageTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Image View was tapped.");
}

@end
```

同様の組み込みは、UILabelにもできます。

Comment: 外側のviewと内部のUIimageViewの両方がuserInteractionEnabled:YESになっていると外側のviewにeventを発行しても、UIImageViewはソレに反応しないので、むしろNOにしておく必要がありました。